# Mapping/variable in struct. Which one is cheaper in terms of gas?

Tags: solidity, gas, mapping, struct, gas-estimate

Considering the following different approaches:

**1st approach**

```
struct Apartment {
  string apartmentAddress;
  string description;
  string image;
}

struct Reservation {
  Apartment apartment;
  uint32 start;
  uint32 end;
}
```

**2nd approach**

```
struct Apartment {
  string apartmentAddress;
  string description;
  string image;
}

struct Reservation {
  uint32 apartmentId;
  uint32 start;
  uint32 end;
}
```

**3rd approach**

```
struct Apartment {
  string apartmentAddress;
  string description;
  string image;
}

struct Reservation {
  uint32 start;
  uint32 end;
}

//mapping the reservationId to the apartmentId
mapping (uint => uint) reservationToApartment;
```

Which approach is cheaper in terms of gas? And why?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It depends on the usage. Just measure the gas consumption with your use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use foundry locally it will say how much gas each function costs.